# AWS CDK Typescript Lambda Handler Event Type

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I'm using CDK to create my serverless app, and I current have a lambda trigger by an S3 put event, like so:

```
const function = new NodejsFunction(this, `id-here`, {
            entry: path.join(__dirname, '/../src/lambda/index.ts'),
            ...more props
        });

function.addEventSource(new eventsources.S3EventSource(this.myBucket, {
            events: [ s3.EventType.OBJECT_CREATED ],
            filters: [ ... ]
        }));
```

I can't seem to find, by looking through the docs, what `type` I should be using in my typescript handler:

```
export const handler  = (event: <What goes here?>) => {

    //some stuff

    return someThing
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The events your Lambda receives will be of the type [S3Event](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/aws-lambda/trigger/s3.d.ts) from the [@types/aws-lambda](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/aws-lambda) package:

```js
export interface S3Event {
    Records: S3EventRecord[];
}
```

Comment: Thanks @fedonev! I'm new to Typescript and didn't realise it would be in a separate package!